# Check if value stays the same for 10 consecutive days

Tags: python, pandas

I have an input like this:

```
Date        X    Y  Value
2024-01-10  X1  123 1
2024-01-11  X1  123 3
2024-01-12  X1  123 2
2024-01-13  X1  123 5
2024-01-14  X1  123 6
2024-01-15  X1  123 2
2024-01-16  X1  123 2
2024-01-17  X1  123 2
2024-01-18  X1  123 3
2024-01-19  X1  123 2
2024-01-20  X1  123 2
2024-01-10  X2  456 4
2024-01-11  X2  456 4
2024-01-12  X2  456 4
2024-01-13  X2  456 4
2024-01-14  X2  456 4
2024-01-15  X2  456 4
2024-01-16  X2  456 4
2024-01-17  X2  456 4
2024-01-18  X2  456 4
2024-01-19  X2  456 4
2024-01-20  X2  456 4
```

Id like to get output only where Value didn't change for 10 consecutive days, based on X and Y combination

In this example the output I would like to get would be:

```
Date        X    Y    Value
2024-01-20  X2  456    4.
```

This date specifically because the date is newest.

Comment: What code did you write to attempt to solve this?  Is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: use a queue of max length 10, iterate over the DF fill the queue and test if length is 10 and all elements are the same

Comment: Are you guaranteed to have one and only one row per date?  No gaps?

Comment: you first need to read this input in some variable before processing it. The input you wrote is not valid python, so we cannot really help you without knowing what data structure are you using to store it

Comment: Is the input sorted by date as with your example?

Answer (score 2):

You can for groups of consecutive days, identical groups and values, get the [`last`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.last.html) and filter by [`size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html):

```
N_days = 10

# ensure datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# ensure data is sorted by groups, then date
tmp = df.sort_values(by=['X', 'Y', 'Date'])

# form groups of consecutive data
# by successive dates and identical ID/Value
group = (tmp['Date'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1))
         |
         tmp[['X', 'Y', 'Value']]
         .ne(tmp[['X', 'Y', 'Value']].shift())
         .any(axis=1)
        ).cumsum()

# form grouper
g = df.groupby(group)

# get last row (date) per group
# only keep if group size ≥ N_days
out = g.last()[g.size().ge(N_days)]

print(out)
```

Output:

```
        Date   X    Y  Value
9 2024-01-20  X2  456      4
```

Comment: With minor tweaks it does the job, to be exact had to do:
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])  
and
group = (tmp['Date'].diff().ne('1d') change this to
group = (tmp['Date'].diff().ne(pd.Timedelta(days=1)) (maybe im missing something here?)

Anyways thank you very much!

Comment: @tin yes, you indeed need a datetime type and the second change might depend on your pandas version. I'll update